# Find residue of $f(z) = \dfrac{\cos z}{(z^2 + 1)^2}$ at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Find residue of $f(z) = \dfrac{\cos z}{(z^2 + 1)^2}$ at $z=\infty$. I am new to this topic. First of all I can consider the function $f(1/z)$ and thus find its residue on $z=0$. Then, I can see that $z=0$ is a pole. So I can find the order of this pole and apply a famous formula, which is something that includes a limit and a higher order derivative, so the calculation of it is tedious. Is there any other easier way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically [you want to consider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity#Definition) $\frac{-1}{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac{-z^2\cos(1/z)}{(1+z^2)^2}$. Can you see why the $1/z$ coefficient is $0$ without the "tedious" calculation you've tried?

Comment: @J.G. I guess because $z^2$ has an even exponent?

Comment: I think you're trying to say the function is even, so yes, that's it.