# Find residue of $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{(z^2+1)^2}$ at $z = \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

Find residue of $f(z) = \dfrac{\sin z}{(z^2+1)^2}$ at $z = \infty$. Then this is the same as finding the residue at $z=0$ for $\dfrac{-1}{z^2}f(1/z)= \dfrac{-z^2 \sin 1/z}{(z^2+1)^2}$

$z = 0$ is a pole. But $z^n \sin 1/z \to \infty$ when $z \to 0, n = 1,2,3...$ Also the denominator is not $0$ when $z=0$. So I can't use famous formulas. Now, $-z^2\sin 1/z = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty {\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)!z^{2n-1}}}$. But what I should do with $(z^2+1)^2$ I don't know. Also, the answer is $1/2e$ which suggests me that there is something tricky. Should I evaluate an integral over some circle? Also, I know that the residue at $z=\infty$ of $g(z) = \dfrac{\cos z}{(z^2+1)^2}$ is $0$, so $-\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}{g(z)dz}=0$, can this fact be of help? Any hints will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: "z=0 is a pole". Why?

Comment: @user1046533 because $z \sin 1/z -> \infty$ as $z ->0$. I reach this conclusion using l'hopital.

Comment: That's not what a pole means.

Comment: @user1046533 having a pole on $z$ is equivalent to having a zero for $1/f(z)$ on $z$.

Comment: When you write $z=0$ is a pole, which function are you referring to? Are you talking about the function $g(z)=\frac{-1}{z^2}f(1/z)$?

Comment: "because sin1/−>∞ as −>0"  This is not true. Think about the case when $z$ is real.

Comment: @user1046533 I see. I had gone with l'hopital. does this mean that l'hopital doesn't work on complex plane? or is it just an error in my calculations? I have seen a post that shows there is an analogue rule to l'hopital for complex plane

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602650/is-lhopitals-rule-applicable-to-complex-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\frac{-z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}$ is holomorphic near $z=0$. So you can expand it as a power series at $z=0$:
$$
\frac{-z^2}{(z^2+1)^2}=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots\tag{1}
$$
where you can work out the coefficients by looking at the Taylor expansion of $\frac{z}{(z^2+1)^2}$ at $z=0$ and then multiply by $-z$.

Using the expansion of $\sin(z)$, you can write the Laurent series for $\sin(\frac1z)$ as
$$
\frac1z-\frac{1}{3!z^3}+\frac{1}{5!z^5}-\cdots\tag{2}
$$
Now multiply the two series (1) and (2) to find the coefficient of $\frac1z$:
$$
(a_0-\frac{a_2}{3!}+\frac{a_4}{5!}-\frac{a_6}{7!}+\cdots)\frac1z
$$

---

To find out the exact coefficients, observe that:
\begin{align}
\frac{-z^2}{(1+z^2)^2} &= \frac{z}2(\frac{1}{1+z^2})'
=\frac{z}2(1-z^2+z^4+\cdots)'\\
&=\frac{z}2(-2z+4z^3-6z^5+\cdots)\\
&=\frac12(-2z^2+4z^4-6z^6+\cdots)
\end{align}
So
$$
\begin{align}
(a_0-\frac{a_2}{3!}+\frac{a_4}{5!}-\frac{a_6}{7!}+\cdots)
&=\frac12\left(\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{4}{5!}+\frac{5}{6!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{3-1}{3!}+\frac{5-1}{5!}+\frac{6-1}{6!}+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}
+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}
+\frac{1}{6!}-\frac{1}{7!}
+\cdots\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{2e}\;.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What if $(a_0-a_2+a_4-a_6+\cdots)$ doesn't converge?

Comment: And $\frac1z-\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z^5}-\cdots\tag{2}$ isn't the Laurent series for $\sin(\frac1z)$

Comment: @sharding4: Thanks for that. Fixed.

Comment: Should not have $a_0, a_1,a_3,\cdots$ since $\frac{z^2}{(1+z^2)^2}$ is even.

Comment: @xpaul: Coefficients could be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining how you find the taylor expansion!

Comment: @H-a-y-K: you are welcome! I think now you are able to answer your own question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4460743

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$ \frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nnz^{2n-2},\sin \left(\frac1z\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!z^{2n-1}} $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{-1}{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)&=&\dfrac{-z^2 \sin \left(\frac1z\right)}{(z^2+1)^2}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nnz^{2n}\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)!z^{2n-1}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Now you can obtain the coefficient of $\frac1z$ which is easy.